# PyMongo - How to ignore a parameter in query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Is there a way to ignore a parameter when querying documents using PyMongo in one line? For example:

```
db.find_one( { "first_name": firstname, "last_name": lastname, "age": age if age else <ignore this field from querying all together> } ):
```

Comment: You can substitute the `age` field filter `"age": age if age else <ignore ...` with: `"$expr": { "$eq": [ "$age", { "$ifNull": [ age, "$age" ] } ] }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with `$and` and `$or` operators.

1. `$and` - Match *1.1.* and *1.2.* conditions.

   1.1. Match `first_name` and `last_name`.

   1.2. `$or`- Match `age` variable is null or `age` field match with `age` variable.

```
db.find_one({
  $and: [
    {
      "first_name": firstname,
      "last_name": lastname
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              null,
              age
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "age": age
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KPWk0hA0cog)

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ways you can try:

```
filter = { "first_name": firstname, "last_name": lastname }
if age:
    filter["age"] = age

collection.find_one(filter)
```

-OR-

```
filter = { "first_name": firstname, "last_name": lastname }
age_filter = { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$age", { "$ifNull": [ age, "$age" ] } ] } }
filter.update(age_filter)
collection.find_one(filter)
```

-OR- (same as above)

```
collection.find_one({ "first_name": firstname, "last_name": lastname, "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$age", { "$ifNull": [ age, "$age" ] } ] } } )
```